# cv2.error : OPENCV(4.4.0) ERROR(-215 assertion failed) size.height>0 && size,width>0)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

opencv showing an error while displaying an image  here is the code , some one please tell how to resolve it ,picture i am trying to read is[]

```
 import cv2
 img = cv2.imread('Resources/IMG_14_1.jpg')
 cv2.imshow("Output",img)
```

and got the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Harsha/PycharmProjects/opencv/venv/chapter1.py", line 5, in <module>
cv2.imshow("Output",img)    
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-2b5g8ysb\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Comment: Check the shape of img before imshow.

Comment: ashraful it says Nonetype object has no attribute shape

Comment: It seems the image is empty. Can you try with the absolute path to the image and post the result here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your script directory and resources directory is't same.** Copy Resources folder and paste in the Scripts folder and run again.

Comment: it worrked the path was not coorect

Answer (score -1):

This problem happen some time due to file path which causes the issue or if you have a file with the same name or if the extension is incorrect, do a trial and error, i had the same error and i got solution with directroy direction  and it worked out just fine.